# Firedac Change alerter

Tags: delphi, firedac

Trying to implement a firedac change alert on a query, without having it autorefresh the query.
from the docs, if I set the autorefresh = none, then I can [insert confusion here] 'check the value of IFDPhysChangeHandler.ContentModified to determine whether or not you need to refresh the content at a given time.'
great.  this is what I want.  but how do I get to that property?  how can I use this information?

Comment: The documentation http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Data_Change_Notifications_(FireDAC) and http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDEventAlerter seems clear enough. You have to setup a TFDEventAlerter and handle its OnAlert event. What have you tried?

Comment: ... and beware that not all database servers support this feature.